# Pandas DataFrame groupby and aggregate counting on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have started playing with Data Analysis and all the related tools: Pandas, Numpy, Jupyter etc...

The task I am working on is simple, and I could do easily with regular python. However I am more interested in exploring Pandas, and I am looking therefore for a Pandas solution.

I have this simple Pandas DataFrame. The timestamp column is just a Unix timestamp, but to make things more readable I have just put a more comfortable number:

| id | timestamp | success |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9999 | True |
| 2 | 1111 | True |
| 3 | 9999 | False |
| 4 | 1111 | True |
| 5 | 9999 | True |
| 6 | 1111 | True |

I want to group by timestamp, but I want another aggregate column which is the result of the success column: if True count as one, if False count as 0.

I hope the table below clarify what I am trying to achieve. Basically 1111 has three True therefore the sum is 3. 9999 has two True and one False, therefore the sum is 2.

| timestamp | success |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | 3 |
| 9999 | 2 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# The DataFrame
a = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'timestamp': [9999, 1111, 9999, 1111, 9999, 1111],
    'success': [True, True, False, True, True, True]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)

# Group by timestamp and calculate the sum of success
result = df.groupby('timestamp')['success'].sum().reset_index()

# Result
print(result)
```

Do you mean this? You group your data frame by timestamp and then you find the frequency of true values.

Comment: It seems to be working, can you expand each step a little bit more, in particular what reset_index does ?

Comment: `reset_index()` removes the old indexes and set back to deafault 0, 1, 2. You can try removing it. It gives the same result but with 0 1 infront of 1111 and 9999.

Now about the `sum()` part. Try to replace True and False with numbers. You will see the difference. If I am not mistaken python when you add boolean values translates True to 1 and False to 0. So summing them gives the desired result. If your True and False values were number we couldn't use this method to find the frequency.